# VB6 Code to check if User needs to "Run As Administrator"

Tags: vb6, uac, administrator

Several users of my visual basic 6 application must "run as administrator"
Others, do not and can just double click.

Is there a code that I can add as the program opens to check if Run As Aministrator is necessary and then open a window to indicate this?

Comment: Somewhat like this mentioned here??http://vbcity.com/forums/t/138413.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use an API to determine if the current user has administrative rights or not.

Luckily, there is one function that returns `0` for `False` to indicate the status of the current user. Namely: [IsUserAnAdmin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776463%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Here is how to declare it and use it:

```
'In a module file:
Public Declare Function IsUserAnAdmin Lib "Shell32" Alias "#680" () As Integer
```

Then in your `Form_Load()`

```
Sub Form_Load()

   If IsUserAnAdmin() = 0 Then 
     MsgBox "Not admin" 
   Else 
     MsgBox "Admin" 
   End If

End Sub
```

**Note**: The Shell function [`IsUserAnAdmin` is depricated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776463.aspx). You can replace the functionality with something like (*pseudocode*):

```
Boolean IsUserAdmin()
{
   PSID administratorsGroup = StringToSid("S-1-5-32-544"); //well-known Administrators group

   Boolean isAdmin;
   if (not CheckTokenMembership(0, administratorsGroup, out isAdmin) then
      isAdmin = false;

   FreeSid(administratorsGroup);

   return isAdmin;
}
```

Comment: You'd want to declare it Public rather than Private or you won't be able to call it from your form (unless you wrap it in a another public function).

Comment: you can declare it as private in your form declarations

Answer (score 0):

Just add the proper "level" value to the application manifest.

Sample manifest fragment:

```
<trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <security>
        <requestedPrivileges>
            <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator"
                                     uiAccess="false"/>
        </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
</trustInfo>
```

This causes Windows to raise the UAC prompt without any special action by the user and without any added code.  Now that Windows XP is dead and buried this works in all supported versions of Windows except lingering remnants of Windows Server 2003 which are scheduled to leave extended support in a matter of months.